# Can I make multiple extra melee attacks with one crit?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Can I make a extra melee attack with **Harmony Blade** and **Two-Weapon Opening** and **Rampage** on the same crit?

If I crit again with **Rampage** can I again make a melee attack with harmony blade and two weapon opening?

- [**Rampage**](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/class.aspx?id=148)<sup>[DDI]</sup>: *Barbarian class feature* - once per round, when you score a critical hit with a barbarian attack power, you can immediately make a melee basic attack as a free action, you do not have to attack the same target that you scorred a critical attack against
- [**Harmony Blade**](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=1479)<sup>[DDI]</sup>: *from item set Blade Dancer's Regalia* - Critical: +1D6 damage per plus, and you can make a melee basic attack with your off-hand weapon.
- [**Two-weapon Opening**](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=349)<sup>[DDI]</sup>: *paragon feat  from the two-weapon fighting chain* - when you are wielding two melee weapons and you score a critical hit with your main weapon, you can make a melee basic attack with your off-hand weaponagainst the same target as free action. (PHB2)

Comment: Added compendium links for the mentioned rule elements for easier reference.

Comment: As a point of order: the intent with limiting free attacks to 1/turn is to prevent infinite action cycles. This, however, breaks different frees contributing to attacks and may be a place where GM leniency is indicated, so long as no one free action procs more than once and the PC isn't playing silly buggers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Maybe

Generally you can, but there's one big exception. You can only ever use one free action to make an attack per turn, regardless from what source that attack comes.

[Free Action](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=118)<sup>[DDI]</sup>:

> Free actions take almost no time or effort. You can take as many free actions as you want during your or another combatant’s turn. There is an exception to that rule: A creature can take a free action to use an attack power only once per turn. Creatures don’t normally have attack powers that can be used as free actions, but some powers and other effects grant the ability to use an attack power (usually a basic attack) as a free action. For example, a character might have two different abilities that let him or her make a melee basic attack as a free action when their respective triggers occur. If both abilities are triggered on the same turn, the character can make only one of the melee basic attacks during that turn. [...]

From my reading you could use the Harmony Blade's critical entry as many times per round as you wanted provided you score the required critical hit. However, all other options to attack that can be used as a free action would share the same 1/turn free action attack limit and couldn't be used in conjunction.

Even with no actions, the main-hand trigger requirement on the following two would mean they can't trigger each other. Rampage can trigger a free attack that can trigger one of the other two, but the other two can not trigger each other because they are made with the off-hand weapon.

Comment: So what kind of action is the harmony blade proc?

Comment: @IainAnderson: To be honest, I don't know. I really hate game design like this, where you can't tell if it's either a No Action or some other sort of action which is implied in some obscure rules text. -_- I'd personally would probably treat it as a No Action.

Comment: I agree with the "No Action" interpretation, even if a "Free Action" could be reasonable too. Also note that the 1 attack free action limit is _per turn_, meaning that you can activate once for each critical scored during an attack of opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things to note:

1. You can only use one free action per turn, for an attack.  So as Arotter said, you can use the Harmony blade as many times as you crit, but not the Rampage + Two handed Opening.
2. It is my understanding, from the text that you have provided, that you can either use Two handed Opening, OR the Harmony blade, but not both.  They are redundant, except for the fact that one is a free action, and the other one is not.

Comment: Harmony Blade and Two Handed Opening are two separate powers that grant extra attacks. Why wouldn't they both trigger on the same crit?